# using os.remove() in os.walk() for loop returns FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm using Python 3.6.4 in the Anaconda command prompt.

I have a function that uses `os.walk()` to loop through all the available files in a root directory.

My code is:

```
def apply_to_files(pattern, base='.') :
    regex = re.compile(pattern)
    matches = []
    completed = ''
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base):
        for f in files:
            if regex.match(f):
                os.remove(f)
```

This triggers a `FileNotFoundError` specifically:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
> specified: 'c.html'

I call the function like:

`apply_to_files('c.*', 'C')`

And the directory in which I am running the function has the structure:

```
root
 -C
  -c.html
  -c.txt
  -c.php
 -B
 -D
```

When I replace `os.remove(f)` with `print(f)` it returns all of the files just fine as you would expect. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `files` variable contain only the filenames. When trying to manipulate the files you have to add the full path:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base):
    for f in files:
        if regex.match(f):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
```

Comment: @logos_164 `print(f)` will print only the filename, without the full path - example: it will print only `c.html` and not `/root/C/c.html` which is the full path to the file, needed to remove it.